# What does having a Parent / Child Relationship really means in Android Ecosystem?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-activity, parent-child

I have this dilemma when it is said about two activities having a parent/child relationship in Android ecosystem.

So which one is it:

1. Activity-A spawns Activity-B ?
2. Activity-A spawns Activity-B and Activity-B inherits parent Activity-A ?

Any idea/pointer is appreciated.

Comment: Inherits is a wrong word to use here. Mostly the parent child idea is applicable to Activity and its fragments as far as my knowledge goes.

Comment: There can be multiple interpretations of this.. I request you to be more specific. In Android, A parent-Child relation isn't exactly same as inheritance.

Comment: @ByzantineFailure thanks for replying so quick. Well doesn't parent/child relationship actually means that child `inherits` from it's parent?

Comment: @beerBear - consider your first example.. Activity B doesn't inherit anything from Activity A. The context is at the application level. The parameters on which Activity B is working, is provided by the framework. Activity A just starts activity B. This isn't inheritance. Activity A extends Activity, now this is inheritance. And a parent child relation doesn't always mean inheritance.

Comment: @TheLostMind hmm.. so in #1 we have Act.-A extending(inheriting from `Activity`) and same is for the Act.-B so all in all both Act.-A and Act.-B are inheriting from `Activity` and are having a child-child relationship with each other?

Comment: @beerBear - Activity A and B have a "parent-child" relationship "on the activity stack". And they both inherit from Activity (so, they are kind of siblings..). Like I mentioned in my first comment, What they are (and how they are related) depends on the context...

Comment: @TheLostMind +1 for pointing out relationship on the `Activity Stack` :}